# Simple API Rest python script takes a lot of time (or doesn't end)

Tags: python, python-3.x, here-api

For a business process I need to calculate driving distance between 1 origin and 30 k destinations.

I get both origins and destinations coordinates from a Google Sheet. Destinations is a matrix (approx 100 x 30).

I'm using [HERE](https://www.here.com/)  api to calculate the distance.

The result should be the same destinations matrix but with the distance (in the same order as the destinations coordinates).

This is the part of the script that calculates the distance and, I think, the one which lasts a lot:

```
distance= []
distance= pd.DataFrame(distance)

for row in destinations.itertuples():
    a= row[1:]
    distance1 = []
    for column in a:
        try:
            args = {'waypoint0': 'geo!'+origins, 'waypoint1': 'geo!'+column, 'mode': 'fastest;truck'}
            qstr = urlencode(args)
            url = "https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=xxxx" + qstr
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            dist = json.loads(response.read())['response']['route'][0]['leg'][0]['length']/1000

        except Exception:
            dist = 10000
        distance1.append(dist)
    distance2 = pd.DataFrame(distance1)
    distance2 = distance2.T
    distance = distance.append(distance2)
```

Does anyone think of a better way to make the script to actually finish?

Thanks!!

Comment: If that's really your API key in the URL, change it immediately.

Comment: Why? He could have created domain whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic looks pretty much accurate. If you need to limit the loop count, please check Large-Scale Matrix Routing API if it aligns with the use case.

The Large-Scale Matrix Routing service is a HTTP JSON API for calculating routing matrices with a large number of start and destinations points (e.g. 10,000 x 10,000).

For more details, please refer the following doc :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/api-reference-swagger.html

**Note** : please remove appKey from the shared code snippet